# Character spacing for chart axes in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a macro to change the character spacing for my legend and axes labels on charts from the default 0 to 0.2. I used the record macro function and the result for the legend works fine. Specifically:

```
ActiveChart.Legend.Select
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
    .BaselineOffset = 0
    .Spacing = 0.2
End With
```

But the result for the axes throws up an error when I try to run it myself. e.g:

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
    .BaselineOffset = 0
    .Spacing = 0.2
End With
```

Once I run the second line, it tells me: "Run-time error xxxxx. Method `TextFrame2` of object `ChartFormat` failed"

Any ideas on how I can change the character spacing for axes labels correctly?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the error occurs when trying to access the TextFrame2 property of the axis.
Depending on your exact need a work around might be to set the spacing for the whole chart area at once.

Something along the lines of:

```
with ActiveChart.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
     .Spacing=0.2
end with
```

Comment: Ah fantastic, that does the job perfectly! Thank you for taking the time to reply.